# 2 hour difference in mysql column in datetime format

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have a cronjob which runs every hour. This cronjob should write to database when dataset was updated. My SQL Query in php looks like this

```
INSERT INTO allstats (site_id, adformat_id, imps, clicks, conv, net_pub_comp, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,"'.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").'", "'.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").'")
```

I print out date("Y-m-d H:i:s") and i get 2013-06-28 04:05:17
that is fully right date and time. after that i make a select now() in mysql and time is also the same. timezone on server is set to Europe/Berlin. That timezone is also set in php and mysql. everywhere i get the right time.

But why on insert the datetime column have a value which is 2 hours before the real time? I hope someone have an idea. Thanks for you help.

Comment: The cronjob runs in its own 'environment'.  You can set environment variables (like `TZ`) at the top of the crontab file to make it use the timezone you want.

Comment: Hey thanks for this tip. But i got the problem also if i run the script in ssh via php. So a var like TZ wouldn't help or ?

Comment: Times saved into the database should be in UTC by design, then rendered into local time for display purposes.

Answer (score 2):

If the datetime that you're inserting is the datetime of script execution why not just use `NOW()` in your insert statement?

```sql
INSERT INTO allstats (site_id, adformat_id, imps, clicks, conv, net_pub_comp, created_at, updated_at) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW(),NOW())
```

Less parameters to bind and pass.

Comment: Hey thanks for that tip but with NOW time is also 2 hours to late:(

Comment: Execute in mysql and post the results of `show variables like '%time_zone%';

Comment: hey sorry for long response: thats my output:system_time_zone
CEST
time_zone
SYSTEM

Comment: In your script try execute `SET time_zone = '+2:00';` before insert to change time zone for that particular connection.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL date/times should be stored in the `UTC` time zone. Your application should calculate the difference and convert that date/time into the appropriate time zone.